# Trouble implementing UISearchController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I am having trouble implementing a `UISearchController`

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView` and a few buttons that are below of the table view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    _searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"tableViewHeader %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_tableView.tableHeaderView.frame));
    NSLog(@"searchBar       %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_searchController.searchBar.frame));
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
    ...
}
```

NSLog returns:

```
tableViewHeader {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
searchBar       {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
```

In general I can't seem to get the `tableViewHeader` to be visible. Since I am not using Storyboards, I instantiate the `UITableView` as follows:

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
_tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
_tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIElementsStyleKit tableCellBackground];

[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
```

What could be going wrong?

Thanks

//EDIT:
Just in case it was not implicit, the `UITableView`'s dimensions are defined by `NSLayoutConstraints` and it shows perfectly. The problem is just that the `UISearchBar` does not get displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that I defined the `UISearchController` after having added the `UITableView` as a subview to `self.view`.

As soon as I moved the code before the `[self.view addSubview:_tableView]` everything worked as expected.